# Sci-fi movie where time-travelers(?) journey to ancient Rome/Greece(?)

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, time

I'm trying to remember a movie. The only thing I remember clearly is that there were modern explorers in a land or time that resembles ancient Rome or Greece.

At the end of the movie during a disaster there is this young woman who enters a chamber or something with flames and when she comes out she is old and dies. The "modern explorers" looked like from the 50's.

Comment: The Three Stooges Meet Hercules (1962) (link: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056579/) ?  I watched this many times when I was a kid.  I don't remember the ending though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be the 1965 movie adaption of H. Rider Haggard's [*She,*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059710/) starring Ursula Andress.

from the IMDB page:

> After doing military service in the Middle East, British archaeologist
>   Holly, his valet and his handsome young friend Leo are spotted in
>   Palestine and approached by a mysterious oriental who identified Leo
>   by his uncanny likeness to the portrait on an ancient coin. An
>   adventurous search for the lost Pharaonic city of Kuma proceeds
>   relying on a recently-acquired map. Their hasty mini-expedition
>   reaches a hidden city where the Hellenistic age is still alive. It is
>   ruled by the supernatural Ayesha, 'She who must be obeyed', who
>   believes Leo is is the reincarnation she waited for all those
>   centuries of Callicrates, a companion of Alexander the Great. She
>   offers him immortality and to share the throne as her eternal love,
>   but it goes tragically wrong...

It's a largish image, but here's some thumbnails of *She* aging in the fire:

[image]